# Query that finds the first date a user has surpassed some value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there is a way to write a query that finds the first date ("Purchase_Date") in which a user value of "Purchase_Amount" is above 50$.

Table for example:

```
User_ID Purchase_Date   Purchase_Amount
123A    2020-05-12      20
875C    2020-06-03      15
876N    2020-07-10      50
654D    2020-07-26      10
123A    2020-09-28      35
```

Expected Result

```
User_ID Purchase_Date
123A    2020-09-28
```

On 2020-09-28 the accumulating "Purchase_Amount" passed 50$

Thanks !

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I have updated with expected result, thanks. 
regarding dbms - mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SUM()` window function, if your version of MySql is 8.0+:

```
select t.user_id, min(t.purchase_date) purchase_date
from (
  select *, 
    sum(purchase_amount) over (partition by user_id order by purchase_date) running_total
  from tablename
) t
where t.running_total > 50
group by t.user_id
order by min(t.purchase_date) limit 1
```

If you want the 1st date for all users that have passed 50$ then you can remove the `ORDER BY` clause.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9476166c1aa04ba52c21b68f41292482).
Results:

```
> user_id | purchase_date
> :------ | :------------
> 123A    | 2020-09-28
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks ! I've been thinking about this problem for a few days ...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, assuming you are using a datase server with the LIMIT clause available.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Purchase_amount > 500 ORDER BY Purchase_Date ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this doesn't take into account the accumulated sum ?

Comment: you didn't asked for that,... ;p